# How many actors have portrayed both King Arthur and Robin Hood?

Tags: casting

The late Sean Connery (RIP), among his many roles on stage and screen, played both of the most well-known characters of classic British legend: King Arthur and Robin Hood. Was he the only actor (or, if not, was he the only British actor) to have this distinction?

**How many actors have played both King Arthur and Robin Hood during their career?**

[Question inspired by a meta post at SFF.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13153/31394)

Comment: Not sure how to tag this. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Trying to research this.  Monty Python actors come so close - Graham Chapman plays Arthur in Holy Grail and John Cleese plays Robin Hood in Time Bandits.

Comment: I feel like Errol Flynn should have, although he did not! :p

Comment: Remarkably, Sean Connery's son Jason is a near miss: he played Robin Hood in series three of Robin of Sherwood, and the magician Merlin in Merlin: the Quest Begins.

Comment: Interestingly, Richard Harris played King Arthur in *Camelot*, and guested in Connery's *Robin and Marrion* (as Richard the Lionheart)

Answer (score 7):

### Voice Actor Mel Blanc has played both roles.

In [*Robin Hood Daffy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood_Daffy), Daffy Duck (voiced by Blanc) plays the role of Robin Hood. You might argue that Blanc is actually voicing Daffy Duck, but the character in the short is supposed to be the actual Robin Hood, not a duck merely acting like Robin Hood the way Bugs played a rabbit acting like the character without actually being the character in [*Rabbit Hood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_Hood). The character on screen, voiced by Blanc, was supposed to be the actual Robin Hood (in satirical anthropomorphic duck form).

Blanc voiced King Arthur numerous times. He did so--again as Daffy, this time filling the role of Arthur--in [*Bugs Bunny in King Arthur's Court*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077365/characters/nm0000305). Blanc also voiced an actual human version of King Arthur in [*Knighty Knight Bugs*](https://wbanimation.fandom.com/wiki/King_Arthur), in which Arthur assigns Bugs the task of retrieving the Singing Sword. He also played King Arthur in *The Looney, Looney, Looney Bugs Bunny Movie* and a 1963 Chuck Jones short called [*I was a Teenage Thumb*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077365/characters/nm0000305).

Blanc was American of course, so it is possible that Connery is the only British actor to play both roles on screen.

Comment: Great answer.  I didn't think there would be one.

Comment: Upvoted, but I'll wait to accept and see if there's anyone else who either (a) played the characters physically, not just by voice, or (b) was British like Connery.

Answer (score 7):

[Patrick Bergin](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000920/?ref_=nmls_hd)

Played [Sir Robert Hode in 1991](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102797/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_106).

Played [King Arthur in 2000](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0193318/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_73)

Only one I can find, apart from Connery.